# How to convert the Controller to ajax call

Tags: jquery, spring

I have following controller , I would like to call it from ajax request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadpdf/{fileName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
     public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> download(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {
      System.out.println("Calling Download:- " + fileName);
      ClassPathResource pdfFile = new ClassPathResource("D://images//sample.pdf");
```

How jquery can call this type of requestmapping.

Answer (score 0):

Just send a get request with the filename as part of the path as is.if filename is a.txt call:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "https://yourdomain/downloadpdf/a.txt",
        type: 'GET',
    ....
```

Comment: Show your controller and which class include it, there may be other mapping

Answer (score 0):

append the filename to the url of the simple ajax GET request

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://xxxx.com/downloadpdf/abc.pdf,
        method: 'GET', 
        succ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : https://xxxx.com/downloadpdf/abc.pdf,
            contentType : 'application/pdf',
            success : function(data) {
                window.location.href = data;     
            },
            error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                // error handling
            }
        });
```